# ASP.NET WebAPI create file and save it for future download and delete after download

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an `ASP.NET WebAPI` project where I need to generate XLS or PDF's depending on the client (`jQuery`) request.

Because it's not possible to download a file using `$.ajax`, the approach is pretty simple:

1. I will request via `$.ajax` the generation of the file (XLS or PDF) on server.

> but instead of sending the response from server to the client I will save the file locally. The filename will be: **some_token.xls**. The token should be unique. Maybe a GUID.
>
> After the file is generated and saved on server, the method will response with a `200 status` and the token just generated (that actually is the filename).
>
> My `jQuery` ajax request method will enter into `success function` and then will append the "src" property of an IFrame with the path and token of the just generated file.
>
> The server will download the file and will delete it.
>
> So my jQuery ajax looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    // the url used to generate the file and save it on server
    url: '/api/requestfile',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            // if the file was created successfuly on server then download the file
            var iframe = $("<iframe/>").attr({
                src: 'api/downloadfile/' + data.filetoken, // filetoken generated in server
                style: "visibility:hidden;display:none"
            }).appendTo(buttonToDownloadFile);
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong');
        }
    }
})
```

So I have several questions:

> a) Where is the right server path to save the file that I will generate? (AppData, customFolder..?

---

> b) Is there any best practice to create tokens as file names or just using a GUID is fine?

---

> c) How can I delete the file in server once it's downloaded? The file won't be accessed by any other user because the file is created by request. So it's a one time file.

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

> a) The solution was to create a "TempFiles" directory inside App_Data folder that is used to store data.
>
> b) I create a random function to generate a token:

```
public static string GetRandomToken(int length) {
    int intZero = '0';
    int intNine = '9';
    int intA = 'A';
    int intZ = 'Z';
    int intCount = 0;
    int intRandomNumber = 0;
    string strDownloadToken = "";
    Random objRandom = new Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    while (intCount < length) {
        intRandomNumber = objRandom.Next(intZero, intZ);
        if (((intRandomNumber >= intZero) &&
            (intRandomNumber <= intNine) ||
            (intRandomNumber >= intA) && (intRandomNumber <= intZ))) {
            strDownloadToken = strDownloadToken + (char) intRandomNumber;
            intCount++;
        }
    }
    return strDownloadToken;
}
```

> c) Because I'm using WebAPI the delete is a little bit different. I had to create a Filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
    // here I added the code to delete the file.
    // this Filter is executed after the file response have been sent to server so its safe now to delete the file
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this post?http://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/426422

Comment: Yes but I prefer my own implementation because I might migrate this to ExtJS.

Comment: Why notthen examine the plugin code and adapt it?

Comment: Thats a good approach, but my questions are more about server side.

Comment: If you do the client like this you wont need a physical file.

Comment: You can store in temp though. Just track its name if you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments @MikeCheel is probably right about how to build this, but if you are intent on building a server side solution

> A) Where is the right server path to save the file that I will
>   generate? (AppData, customFolder..)

Custom folder that is NOT accessible to the outside world. Then create a handler that serves up the file based on say a url parameter. IE. mywebsite.com/getFile?id=23434234 or some such. In the handler you can easily add security and other checks. Also it will come in handy for C.

You could of course go with a custom folder that is accessible, but that's usually frowned upon

> b) Is there any best practice to create tokens as file names or just
>   using a GUID is fine?

No real best practice, you'd like them to not be easily guessable. A Guid would work fine.

> c) How can I delete the file in server once it's downloaded? The file
>   won't be accessed by any other user because the file is created by
>   request. So it's a one time file.

If you use the handler above, you can serve up the file and then delete it. Otherwise you might need a process that periodically deletes the temp files. Without a handler, I'm not sure how to keep track that the file was actually downloaded the one time or if it was never downloaded, or downloaded 100 times.

Comment: I will complete the answer in my question.